# Is there a reason to fork an organizational repository that I have access to?

Tags: git, github

I've been granted access to a repo under my organization. In this case, does it still make sense to fork the repo to my account? Even without forking, I can create new branches and PRs on the organizational repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to fork a repository you have direct access.

You need to create a feature branch dedicated to your contribution, that you will push to that repository, and you will make a PR from that branch to `master`.

`master` should be a [protected branch](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches#branch-protection-settings), preventing you to push directly to it, forcing the pull-request workflow.

Comment: so clone will do?

Comment: @AnnieJefferson Yes, clone, then `git switch -C myBranch`, (... work...), `git push -u origin myBranch`